# Having problems getting variable values in rotate function in javascript/svg/d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

```
<script>
    for(i = 0;i < 12;i++) {
        svg.append("polygon")
           .attr("points", "0,0.9511, 1.0,0.95111, 1.309,0,  1.618,0.9511, 2.618,0.9511, 1.809,1.5388, 2.118,2.4899, 1.309,1.9021, 0.5,2.4899, 0.809,1.5388")
           .attr("transform", "translate(850, 350), scale(8),rotate(30*i, 800,350)")
           .style("fill", "yellow");
    }
</script>
```

This is my code for a star.I have to make a design of 12 stars around 800,350 with radius around 50.
The issue is 30*i is interpreted as 30*i instead of the multiplication as
0,30,60,90.... degrees.
This is really strange because i was able to access values in past without calculations in the rect transformations.

Please dont tell me to calculate the values of x,y by using 
x=a+rcos theta. I want to do it the other way which is more elegant
Also please be nice I am new to this language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable 'i' is rendered as the string 'i' and not as the degree value.
Try changing your code to something similar to the code below and see if it solves your problem:

```
for(i=0;i<12;i++)
{

svg.append("polygon").attr("points", "0,0.9511, 1.0,0.95111, 1.309,0,  1.618,0.9511, 2.618,0.9511, 1.809,1.5388, 2.118,2.4899, 1.309,1.9021, 0.5,2.4899, 0.809,1.5388")
.attr("transform", `translate(850, 350), scale(8),rotate(30*${i}, 800,350)`)
.style("fill", "yellow");
}
```

I've changed the attribute string value "translate(850, 350), scale(8),rotate(30*i, 800,350)" to use the actual value of 'i' using a templated string :  `translate(850, 350), scale(8),rotate(30*${i}, 800,350)`

Comment: After doing ${30*i} Now it seems to get the right degrees but doesnt rotate anything. I think it is still multiplying the numbers and then converting back to string i.e, "30","60","90" Also can you pls tell me why you use `` instead of the standard " " . The standard is giving an error for some reason.

Comment: @pootispencerhere , could you please provide a more complete sample of your code so that we can see the exact problem?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OcKfbes55BwvMSHsceM9zU93ZSAX_kJp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @pootispencerhere do not add comma in between the transformation parts

Comment: @rioV8 attr("transform", `translate(850 350) scale(8) rotate(${30*i} 800 350)`) do you mean here? Anyways after I removed there is no change.

Comment: @pootispencerhere keep the `comma` in between the `()`

Comment: @ShaiAharoni the problem was it was interpreting stuff right to left. once I made rotate at the left it worked perfectly.